# Can I ellipse a clipping mask on the bottom only?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a curved clipping mask on an image in CSS.

The curve is essentially just the bottom half of a very wide ellipse.

A requirement is that the angle/curvature does not change based on the height/width of the image - it should always stay consistent.

Here is a visual:

### [image: Ellipse clipping mask on bottom only?]

**Attempt 1: border-radius/overflow hidden/fixed width**

*Issue: height of image impacts curvature, no max width*

```css
img { max-width: 100%; vertical-align: top; }
.block { max-width: 320px; background: blue; }
.block-2 { max-width: 200px; background: blue; }

.curve {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="curve">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/320x180" />
  </div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="block-2">
  <div class="curve">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/320x100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Attempt 2: the obvious one - crop image**

*Issue: still not consistent between sizes but close. However client/CMS may mean not an option.*

### [image]

**Attempt 3: clip-path**

*Issue: inconsistent curve, flakey support, no IE support whatsoever*

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

```css
.img1 { 
  max-width: 240px; 
  clip-path: ellipse(150% 100% at 50% 0); 
  -webkit-clip-path: ellipse(150% 100% at 50% 0); 
}
.img2 { 
  max-width: 320px; 
  clip-path: ellipse(150% 100% at 50% 0);
  -webkit-clip-path: ellipse(150% 100% at 50% 0);
}
.img3 { 
  max-width: 640px; 
  clip-path: ellipse(150% 100% at 50% 0);
  -webkit-clip-path: ellipse(150% 100% at 50% 0);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/640x320" class="img1" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/550x100" class="img2" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/640x320" class="img3" />
```

---

**Attempt 4: CSS mask**

*Issue: inconsistent curve affected by width/height, no IE support.*

```css
img { 
  mask: url(http://s17.postimg.org/qo8izn6kf/mask.png) top center / 120% 100%; 
  -webkit-mask: url(http://s17.postimg.org/qo8izn6kf/mask.png) top center / 120% 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/640x320" width="240" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/640x320" width="320" />

<br />

<img src="http://placehold.it/640x100" width="480"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
```

---

**Attempt 5: reverse image crop**

*Issue: relies on additional image/s with colours baked in. Similar to attempt 2 - very close*

```css
body { background: red; }
div { position: relative; display: inline-block; }
img { max-width: 100%; vertical-align: top; }
.mask { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; width: 100% }
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/640x320" width="320" />
  <img class="mask" src="http://s15.postimg.org/c37ncbvxn/curve_mask.png" />
</div>

<br /><br />

<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/640x320" width="480" />
  <img class="mask" src="http://s15.postimg.org/c37ncbvxn/curve_mask.png" />
</div>

<br /><br />

<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
  <img class="mask" src="http://s15.postimg.org/c37ncbvxn/curve_mask.png" />
</div>

<br /><br />

<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x300" />
  <img class="mask" src="http://s15.postimg.org/c37ncbvxn/curve_mask.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: @Brad, your handling of this Q&A has been brought to [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391240/why-a-moderator-removed-multiple-answers-to-append-them-to-the-question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Attempt 6: transparent :before with mega-border + overflow**

*Issue: has fixed size but works so long as larger than site width/image height! Feels dirty though...*

Note: whilst the curves do not look equal, they are all accurate chunks of the same curvature/angle.

```css
div { position: relative; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; }
img { max-width: 100%; vertical-align: top; }

div:before { 
  content: ""; 
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: -100px; 
  left: 50%; 
  margin-left: -900px;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1600px;
  border-radius: 100%; 
  border: 100px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/320x120" /></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/480x240" /></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x220" /></div>
```

Hat-tip: http://jonmifsud.com/blog/inverse-border-radius-in-css/

Comment: Out of all of your answers I think this is the one I would go for, this seems to be the best solution for getting a consistent curvature no matter what image size or placement.

Comment: Thanks @lukehillonline, also has formidable browser support.

Comment: Yes this is very true, you have done well to think of 6 different variations, I am stuck to think of any more. I agree with you that this does feel a bit dirty, but sometimes the dirty way is the only way.