# Curved bottom border with background-image

Tags: html, css

I have a big problem finding a solution to this problem.

I have seen many samples of creating a container with curved `bottom border` exactly as I want but they all have plain or gradient `background-color`.

I need a `container` with a `background-image` and a curved `bottom border` and a bottom border color  like you see in the picture.

[image]

The problem with all samples which I have seen is that the `background-image` gets **distored** if I use the common way of applying the `bottom border` using `CSS`.

This is a plain and simple html structure so if you want to help, you have a reference.

```
<div class="wrapper" style="background-image:url('images/someimage.jpg');">
  <p>some text on the background image</p>
  <a href="#">A button </a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how would i solve this problem is: 
i photoshop the background image
or
i curve the next element to the image element

i guess, there is no direct css property which curves the background image!
(correct me if i'am wrong)

Comment: @mplungjan - if you look at the corners of the curved border, you'll see that it goes all the way up, this is exactly what I'm talking about, border-bottom-*-radius doesn't do the trick. And any effort for expanding the width will distore the image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766857/css-ellipse-clipping-mask-on-bottom-only

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into using `clip-path`, it's not a perfect solution and will require some tweaking of the numbers to get it to look how you wish.

See the below example:

```css
main {
  height:500px;
  background-color:#ccc;
}

.wrapper {
  background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/id/1039/1280/720');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  height:350px;
  clip-path: ellipse(100% 60% at 50% 40%);
}
```

```html
<main>

  <div class="wrapper"></div>
  
  <h2>This is some more content</h2>
</main>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xah82n9d/)

More Information can be found: [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/creating-non-rectangular-headers/)